# Permission to create new 'Environment' for Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops-pipelines

I need to create a new 'Environment' for an Azure devops pipeline. I've come across [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/834604/unable-to-create-environment-in-azure-devops-proje.html), which says I need to have the 'Basic' access level as a user, instead of 'Stakeholder'. I don't have permission to change this though, and I don't have any access to an admin account for Azure Devops (I'm not a member of any of the top-level roles like 'Project Collection Administrators'. Is there any way I can restore access fir a higher level admin account, if there is no access to the original account credentials?